# Count Duplicates in Java 8 using Streams Based on Field

Tags: java, java-8

Am trying to count how many items are duplicated from a list of Item objects. Items are duplicates if they have the same id.

e.g.

```
[5, 5, 2, 4, 2]
```

The ids 5 and 2 both occur more than once, so answer is 2.

---

```
public class Item {

    int id;

    public Item(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DuplicateItems {

    public static int count(List<Item> items) {
        int count = 0;
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        items.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Item::getId));
        Map<Object, Long> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        items.forEach(e -> resultMap.put(e, resultMap.getOrDefault(e, 0L) + 1L));
        System.out.println(resultMap.size());
        return count;
    }

    private static List<Items> convertToList(int[] values) {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int num : values) {
            items.add(new Item(num));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] itemsArray = {5, 5, 2, 4, 2};
        List<Item> items = convertToList(itemsArray);
        int duplicateCount = count(items);
        System.out.println("Duplicate Count: " + duplicateCount);
    }
}
```

---

When I run the program, it says this:

`Duplicate Count: 5`

Why is the value not 2?

Comment: You receive `5` because your `Item` class does not override `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode`. If you implement those properly, it'll output `3`, as you're printing the size of the map.

Comment: You don't seem to be modifying the value of count anywhere. And, there is no `Items` object.

Comment: @BlackPearl - Thanks, that was a typo, just edited it.

Comment: @HadiJ - ```toMap``` is red in IntelliJ IDEA, what is the package name to use?

Comment: It comes from `java.util.stream.Collectors` class. Either import that class and use `Collectors.toMap` or add static import to that method.

Comment: @HadiJ & @Pshemo - thank but when I put the following static import inside my class in IntelliJ IDEA: ```import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;```, the ```toMap``` was fixed (wasn't red anymore) but ```()->1``` has a curly red line underneath it. IntelliJ states this ```Cannot infer functional interface type```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This puts them in a map based on frequency and then counts the number of values greater than 1.

```
       long dups = list2.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.counting()))
               .values().stream().filter(i-> i > 1).count();

       System.out.println(dups);
```

Comment: this worked! May I ask you what the ```filter(i-> i > 1)```, sorry, I am new to Streams.

Comment: Filter is a method of the `stream interface` that takes a `Predicate` (see JavaDoc) and returns `true or false` based on evaluating the condition.  Only items in the stream that evaluate to true are passed thru for further processing.  In the example above, all I did was count those whose map values were greater than 1.

Answer (score 3):

you are doing so many steps that are misleading or wrong, why not simply:

```
items.stream()
     .map(Item::getId)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         Function.identity(),
         Collectors.counting()
     ))
     .values()
     .stream()
     .filter(x -> x > 1)
     .count();
```

that is : first collect to a `Map`, then count only those values that are `> 1`